# Magento2.1 change product attribute via mysql

Tags: magento-2.1, database

I have a Magento 2.1 website and have setup a product attribute to be a drop down. However now I want to change the drop down to be a multi-select. I am wondering how I can do this via mysql. I have seen a few posts on how to do this in Magento 1.x however I am having an issue finding the needed mysql to run to change my product attribute from drop down to multi-select.

The product attribute I want to change has an id of 93

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do that go to `eav_attribute` table field name `frontend_input`.Search that `attribute_id` and change that `frontend_input` to `multiselect`

Comment: thank you. I did not realize it would be that simple.